# Webpack module federation and SAML SSO

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, saml, webpack-module-federation

Currently we have 2 applications that are build in different server groups. Each server group is protected with SAML SSO.
1-st application - is a parent that calls 2-nd application (which is microfrontend). Everything is configured to work using Webpack Module Federation.

The problem is, when user is only authenticated in 1-st application and Module Federation makes call to retrieve microfrontend component - in response it gets auto submit form that is used to auto authenticate user in 2-nd server group:
[image]
But nothing happens...
If user has sessions in both server groups - than everything is OK.

The question is: how to deal with SAML SSO? Ideally i would expect that this auto-submit form will be submitted, user will get authenticated and call to microfrontend will be done after that without any problems.